# Remove the & sign using php preg_replace

Tags: php

How can i strip / remove all spaces and `&` signs of a string in PHP?

I have a string like `$string = "this is my string & this also";` the output should be `"thisismystringthisalso"`

How can I achieve this?

My current code does not replace the `&` sign:

```
<?php $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php $string = preg_replace('/(\s|&(amp;)?)+/', '', $string);?>
```

It replaces:

- white chars (space, tab, ...)
- "&"
- "&" html entity (`&amp;`)